# Fastest way to get most recent commit for a file in git

Tags: git

There are a few answers about getting the most recent commit for a file.  The answers boil down to "git log --all --pretty=format:%H -- path."

Note the --all to search the whole graph.

git log is very slow.  It seems to take a few seconds per operation which is painful when you've got thousands of files to look at.  Is there a faster plumbing way to do this?

Comment: git log should be instantaneous. you can also use the `-n 1` option to limit to 1 commit, since you only want the most recent. Don't know if it will speed up but it's worth a try. Also, if you are on windows, there are other reasons git could be slow in general

Comment: git log itself is almost instantaneous.  git log -- path is not.

Comment: Edited to note use of --all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command. This works very fast for me on a large repository that I work on  (million lines of code with history going back 10 years).

```
git log -n 1 -- filename
```

- The `-n 1` gives you the most recent commit
- The `-- filename` narrows down git log to just the filename that you want

Comment: This is too slow, as stated in the question.  Is there something I should investigate as to why it is so slow?

Comment: Edited to note use of --all.

Comment: If the last commit on a file was a long time ago, it may take a while before git will find it. Git has to, essentially, search for the pathname in each commit's object. Then, if the branch had a lot of merges, git has to branch out from each merge, searching each parent's history, etc...

Comment: Some of the files almost certainly are quite old, but others are not and the time taken seems to be similar.